# Failed to Connect to Azure SQL using node.js (tedious module)

Tags: sql, node.js, azure

I want to connect to Azure SQL Database using node.js. I found a documentation in MSDN blog and see I directly use their source code to connect. I have entered the correct credentials and successfully connected to the database.

However, when I execute the query, it says invalid object name, my table is dbo.Users. What is the problem?

[image: Please find the error message here]

```
var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;
var config = {
  userName: 'myusername',
  password: 'mypw',
  server: 'myserver',
  // When you connect to Azure SQL Database, you need these next options.  
  options: { encrypt: true, database: 'mydb' }
};
var connection = new Connection(config);
connection.on('connect', function (err) {
  // If no error, then good to proceed.  
  console.log("Connected");
  executeStatement();
});

var Request = require('tedious').Request;
var TYPES = require('tedious').TYPES;

function executeStatement() {
    request = new Request("SELECT * FROM dbo.Users;", function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
var result = "";
request.on('row', function (columns) {
    columns.forEach(function (column) {
        if (column.value === null) {
            console.log('NULL');
        } else {
            result += column.value + " ";
        }
    });
    console.log(result);
    result = "";
});

request.on('done', function (rowCount, more) {
    console.log(rowCount + ' rows returned');
});
connection.execSql(request);
}
```

Comment: I tested your code on my side, it works fine. Could you please double check whether you have the specific table `Users` in your Azure SQL Database. And double check whether the Database schema you are using is `dbo`. And try to remove `dbo` in your query stmt. Looking forward to your update.

Comment: I have checked my database information. I found that my table name is "Table" instead of "Users", and the schema is dbo.

Comment: However, when I use "SELECT * FROM Table;" or "SELECT * FROM dbo.Table;" in the query line, it shows error message "Incorrect syntax near the keyword Table"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comment, as your original question, you just mistaken the table name as

> I have checked my database information. I found that my table name is "Table" instead of "Users", and the schema is dbo.

And now you are facing issue:

> "Incorrect syntax near the keyword Table".

As the `Table` is a keyword in MSSQL, you can find it in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx. In SQL sentence, we will use `[]` to contain the table name if the table name has a conflict with any keyword.

Try to use `SELECT top 1 * FROM [Table]`. Furthermore, it is better to rename the table named `Table` to resolve the conflicts.

Comment: If it is helpful for you, you can mark it as answer, which is benefit for communities who are facing the same issue with you. Thanks.